# Stripe module issues at Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am developing a project which integrates Stripe + Parse for iOS. It uses web hooks and Cloud code via node js. Currently i am in need of implementing a couple of functions:

1. cancel user subscription with flag atPeriodEnd;
2. subscribe cancelled customer once again (named multiple subscriptions via Stripe docs).

As for the first one: I'm sending a request as follows in Parse's API -

```
Stripe.Customers.cancelSubscription(request.params.customerID, 1, null)
```

but the second parameter, i.e. atPeriodEnd remains 0 when i receive Stripe's response and my webhook catches request for cancelling user immediately. Also i have checked Stripe's dashboard to see parameters that i pass and it says 'No query parameters'. Hope you can help me with this one out.

Second one: as i mentioned earlier user needs to have ability to subscribe once again after cancellation. That means that i already have a valid customer saved at Stripe and all i need is to 'attach' to him a new subscription. There is a method for this at Stripe docs:

```
stripe.customers.createSubscription("cus_00000000000", { plan: "planName" }, function(err, subscription) {  
});
```

But i can't find similar to this in Parse's API. Hope you can help with this one out.

Sorry if there are some mistakes or misunderstandings for you - feel free to ask, i will answer as much clear as i can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to #1 - make an http call directly to the stripe endpoint using Parse.Cloud.httpRequest. (I agree that Stripe.Customers.cancelSubscription in the Parse cloud module does not seem to be working)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("cancel", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    var customerStripeId = user.get("stripeId");
    var key = "<stripe_api_key>"
    var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/" + customerStripeId + "/subscription"

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'DELETE',
        params: { at_period_end: true, key: key },
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            response.success()
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Delete failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.failure()
        }
    });

});
```